# How to install and use open source library on Windows?

Tags: makefile, open-source, cmake, build-system

I'd like to use open source library on Windows. (ex:Aquila, following http://aquila-dsp.org/articles/iteration-over-wave-file-data-revisited/) But I can't understand anything about "Build System"... Everyone just say like, "Unzip the tar, do configure, make, make file" at Linux, but I want to use them for Windows. There are some several questions.

i) Why do I have to "Install" for just source code? Why can't I use these header files by copying them to the working directory and throw #include ".\aquila\global.h" ??

ii) What are Configuration and Make/Make Install? I can't understand them. I just know that configuration open source with Windows need "CMake", and it is configuration tool... But what it actually does??

iii) Though I've done : cmake, mingw32-make, mingw32-make install... My compiler said "undefined references to ...". What this means and what should I do with them?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to install for sources. You do need to install for the libraries that get built from that source code and that your code is going to use.

`configure` is the standard name for the script that does build configuration for the software about to be built. The usual way it is run (and how you will see it mentioned) is `./configure`.

`make` is a build management tool (as the tag here on SO will tell you). One of the most common mechanisms for building code on linux (etc.) is to use the `autotools` suite which uses the aforementioned `configure` script to generate build configuration information for use by generated makefiles which `make` then uses to build the software. `make` is also the way to run the default build target defined in a makefile (which is often the `all` target and which usually builds the appropriate library/binary/etc.).

`make install` is a specific, secondary, invocation of the `make` tool on the `install` target which (generally) installs the (in this case previously) built code into an appropriate location (in the `autotools`/`configure` universe the default location is generally under `/usr/local`).

`cmake` is, again as the SO tag says, a build system that generates configuration files for other build tools (`make`, `VS`, etc.). This allows the developers to create the build configuration once and build on multiple platforms/etc. (at least in theory).

If running `cmake` worked correctly then it should have generated the correct information for whatever target system you told it to use (`make` or `VS` or whatever). Assuming that was `make` that should have allowed `mingw32-make` to build the software correctly (assuming additionally that `mingw32-make` is not a distinct `cmake` target than `make`). If that is not working correctly then something is still missing from your system (and `cmake` probably should have caught that).

But to give any more detail you will need to give more detail about what errors you are actually getting and from what command.

(Oh, and on Windows, and especially if you plan on building your software with `VS` (or some other non-`mingw32-make` tool) the chances of you needing to run `mingw32-make install` are **incredibly** small).

Answer (score 0):

For Windows use `cmake` or latest `ninja`.

The process is not simple or straight, but achievable. You need to write CMake configuration.

Building process is not simple and straight, that's why there exists language like Java(that's another thing though)

Rely on `CMake` build the library, and you will get the Open-Source library for Windows.

You can distribute this as library for Windows systems, distribute and integrate with your own software, include the Open Source library, in either cases, you would have to build it for Windows.

Writing `CMake` helps, it would be helpful to build for other platforms as well.

**Now Question comes: Is there any other way except CMake for Windows Build**

Would you love the flavor of writing directly Assembly?

If obviously answer is no, you would have to write CMake and generate sln for `MSVC` and other compilers.

Just fix some of the errors comes, read the `FAQ`, `Documentation` before building an Open Source library. And fix the errors as they lurk through.

It is like handling burning iron, but it pays if you're working on something meaningful. Most of the server libraries are Open Source(e.g. age old `Apache httpd`). So, think before what you're doing.

There are also not many useful Open Source libraries which you could use in your project, but it's the way to Use the Open Source libraries.